# Hide the sign in link when ther is a session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a link a the navbar when the user log in : 
there is my code

I want to hide : `<li><a class="secnd" id="toDelete" href="./inscription/index.php">Sign in</a></li>`

**HTML :**

```
 <!-- Right NavBar -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="axit-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="secnd" id="toDelete" href="./inscription/index.php">Sign in</a></li>
                <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['Mail'])) { ?>

                <li><a class="secnd" id="myButton" value="xx" href="#">Log in</a></li>

                <?php  } else { ?>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION['Mail'];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">My invitations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My events</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a  href="logout.php">Se déconnecter</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <?php } ?>
```

**PHP :**

```
// Check for ADMINS
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $mail= $_POST['mailInput'];
    $password= $_POST['passwordInput'];
    $hashedPass= sha1($password);

    // check if the user exist in DB

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Mail, Password FROM connection WHERE Mail= ?  AND Password = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($mail, $hashedPass));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($count > 0) {

        $query = $conn->query("SELECT User_ID FROM connection WHERE Mail='$mail'");
        while ($r = $query->fetch()) {

            if($r['User_ID'] == NULL){
                $_SESSION['Mail'] = $mail;
                header('Location: admin/index.php');
            }else {
                $_SESSION['Mail'] = $mail;
                header('Location:');
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

?>

Comment: $query = $conn->query("SELECT User_ID FROM connection WHERE Mail='$mail'"); -> SQL injection possible here

Comment: Assuming you have set user session on log in, something like `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['User'])) { ?>` would do the trick?

Comment: you've already done that same kind of thing with `email`, why don't you apply same logic to `register` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!-- Right NavBar -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="axit-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Mail'])) { ?>  <li><a class="secnd" id="toDelete" href="./inscription/index.php">Sign in</a></li>
            <?php } if (!isset($_SESSION['Mail'])) { ?>

            <li><a class="secnd" id="myButton" value="xx" href="#">Log in</a></li>

            <?php  } else { ?>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION['Mail'];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">My invitations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My events</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a  href="logout.php">Se déconnecter</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <?php } ?>
```